# Jquery to set height of nested element to the height of its containing element

Tags: jquery, html

I think it is a fairly simple problem, but I just cant wrap my head around it and I am not too great with jQuery. I have a div inside of an . The articles height is variable depending on the content (Its a blog post, so some are short, some are long). I want my div to match the height of the article it is nested in.

HTML:

```
    <article class="PostHome">
    <div class="ColorBarLeft"></div>
        <header>
            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h3>
            <small>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateCreated)</small>
        </header>

        <section id="PostContent">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
        </section>

        <section id ="PostTags">
            @Html.Label("Tags:")
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tags)
        </section>

        @Html.ActionLink("View Full Post", "Post", new { blogTitle = item.Title.Replace(" ", "-"), id = item.Id}, null)
    </article>
```

And then I tried some jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".ColorBarLeft").height(function () {
    var height = $(this).height()
    $('.PostHome').height(height);
})
});
```

I think that code is correct, but it could be off, again, not very good at jQuery.

And I don't know if this is important but there are going to be multiple posthomes and ColorBarlefts on the page at a time.

***EDIT, changes id=PostHome to class=PostHome

[image]

I want the bar where the red squiggly box is.

Comment: It seems like you're doing it the other way around matching the height of `posthome` to `colorbarleft`

Comment: There are 2 separate issues here: the height, and the position of the colored bar. Do you already have a solution for the position? How the bar is positioned will likely determine what options are available for the height.

Comment: For the position all I was doing was setting the div's css to this: position: absolute; left: 0;. For the height I can't get it to match, which is why i though jQuery might do it. If I use the images like you stated, it works fine, but only if I keep it inside the article element

Comment: Given that `position:absolute;` works for the position, that establishes that there are no relevant ancestor elements with `position:relative;` (an important detail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to add the color bar as a bg image to the article, rather than by adding a div. And if needed, give the article left padding equal to the width of the color bar.

Another option is to have the div act as a wrapper around all of the content inside the article, and add the color bar (bg image and optional left padding) to the div.

In both cases, the bg image will be applied to an element that's naturally guaranteed to have the correct height, without any assistance from jQuery. This is especially useful if the content is likely to change in height while the page is open, as it doesn't require updating the height using jQuery.

**Edit:**

I think the only CSS-only solution (that doesn't require jQuery/JavaScript) is if the article is in a separate container from the content above and below, with all 3 containers separately horizontally centered in the page. In that case, the container for the article could have a bg image on the left, and then the article could be given a fixed width and horizontally centered. This avoids the needs for jQuery, doesn't require absolute positioning (which would take the content out of the flow of the layout), and doesn't require updating the height if the content changes while the page is open.

Otherwise, it's back to square one and just finding the right jQuery code to set the appropriate height for the color bar div. Just be sure to reapply the height if the article content dynamically changes.

```
$('.ColorBarLeft').height($('.PostHome').height());
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like that, but I wasn't sure how it would work in my particular case. The PostHomes are sitting in the center of my page and what I am trying to do is have a 20px wide colored bar sit absolute position left. If that makes sense..

Comment: Do you want the colored bar to be on the left edge of the article, or on the left edge of the browser viewport?

Comment: If you want the colored bar to be on the left edge of the article, create a 20px by 1px yellow png image, tile it vertically, position it on the left, and add it to the article: `background:url(bar.png) repeat-y left top;`. You'll have a 20px wide colored bar that occupies the full height. If you don't want the content to overlap it horizontally (as if the colored bar is a separate column), give the article `padding-left:20px;`

Comment: I like the suggestion and it works for what I think you interpretted my vague explanation as :). Check my edit, I threw a picture up with what I am kinda looking for. Let me know if you have any suggestions on it.

Comment: Edited the answer above. Was hoping a CSS-only solution would be possible, but it's probably not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.ColorBarLeft').height( $(".PostHome").innerHeight() + 'px' );
 });
```

If there are multiple `.PostHome` objects, and you would like to target the first one only, then do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.ColorBarLeft').height( $(".PostHome:eq(0)").innerHeight() + 'px' );
 });
```

I am using `innerHeight()` instead of Height, because this method returns the height of the element, including top and bottom padding, in pixels, whereas `Height()` will not return the height with the padding.

http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/

Or you can simply use CSS for this.. In your stylesheet:

```
.ColorBarLeft { height:100%; }
```

But this will only work if the containing object has an explicit height set to it, in px or em, etc, as Matt Coughlin has stated.

Comment: The jQuery semi-works like this. its setting the height, but it is taking the first PostHome height and setting it for all subsequent posts.

Comment: Do you have more objects with `id="PostHome"` ?

Comment: Yeah, there will be about five per page. And I changed it to a class instead of ID

Comment: I believe `height:100%` would only work if the container has an explicit height in px or em.

Comment: Ok, well which one are you trying to target? The first one only?

Comment: If you want to select the first one, then just change it from `#PostHome` to `.PostHome:eq(0)`  0 = the first one.